# Join multiple rdds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 4rdds of type RDD:((int,int,int),values) and my rdds are

```
rdd1: ((a,b,c), value) 
rdd2:((a,d,e),valueA) 
rdd3:((f,b,g),valueB)
rdd4:((h,i,c),valueC)
```

How can i join the rdds like rdd1 join rdd2 on "a" rdd1 join rdd2 on "b" and rdd1 join rdd3 on "c"

so the output is `finalRdd: ((a,b,c),valueA,valueB,valueC,value))`  in Scala ?

I tried doing this with collectAsMap but it didnt work well and throws exception

code just for rdd1 join rdd2

```
val newrdd2=rdd2.map{case( (a,b,c),d)=>(a,d)}.collectAsMap
val joined=rdd1.map{case( (a,b,c),d)=>(newrdd2.get(a).get,b,c,d)}
```

example

```
rdd1: ((1,2,3),animals)
rdd2:((1,anyInt,anyInt),cat)
rdd3:((anyInt,2,anyInt),cow )
rdd 4: ((anyInt,anyInt,3),parrot)
```

the output should be `((1,2,3),animals,cat,cow,parrot )`

Comment: Could you please write a better example, of the data inside the rdds?

Comment: i added an example ,it doesnt matter what number is on anyInt field

Comment: can there be duplicate rows in rdd1? duplicate keys? (e.g. two elements with `(1,2,3)` and value "animal"  and "another-animal")

Answer (score 3):

There is a handy `join` method on RDDs, but you need it to be keyed by you particular join key, which is what Spark uses for partitioning and shuffling.

From [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations):

> join(otherDataset, [numTasks]) : When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and fullOuterJoin.

I can't compile where I am, but by hand it goes something like this:

```
val rdd1KeyA = rdd1.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._1._3. x._2) // RDD(a, (b,c,value))
val rdd2KeyA = rdd2.map(x => (x._1._1, x._2) // RDD(a, valueA)
val joined1 = rdd1KeyA.join(rdd2KeyA) // RDD(a, ((b,c,value), valueA))

val rdd3KeyB = rdd3.map(x => (x._1._2, x._2) // RDD(b, valueB)
val joined1KeyB = joined1.map(x => (x._2._1._1, (x._1, x._2._1._2, x._2._1._3. x._2._2) // RDD(b, (a, c, value, valueA))
val joined2 = joined1KeyB.join(rdd3keyB) // RDD(b, ((a, c, value, valueA), valueB))
```

...and so on

Avoid `collect*` functions since they do not use the distributed nature of your data and are prone to fail on big loads, they shuffle all data on an RDD to an in-memory collection on the master node, probably blowing everything up.